# Use of local variable 'updateTimer' before its declaration Egg timer

Tags: xcode

I just started learning programming and the instructor asked us to make an egg timer app.
I tried to run her example solution but XCode shows an issue with the code at `#selector(updateTimer)`. The error says `Use of local variable 'updateTimer' before its declaration`.

This is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UILabel!
    let eggTimes = ["Soft" :3, "Medium":4, "Hard":6]
    var secondsRemaining = 60
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        timer.invalidate()
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        secondsRemaining = eggTimes[hardness]!
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector:
                                     #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        func updateTimer() {
            if secondsRemaining > 0 {
                print("\(secondsRemaining) seconds left to finish")
                secondsRemaining -= 1
            }
            else {
                timer.invalidate()
                progress.text = "DONE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that the `func updateTimer` is declared under the `#selector` and as such isn't "available yet" to put it simply. What you probably wanted is to move the function outside the `hardnessSelected` as such:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UILabel!

    let eggTimes = ["Soft" :3, "Medium":4, "Hard":6]
    var secondsRemaining = 60
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        self.secondsRemaining = self.eggTimes[hardness]!
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if self.secondsRemaining > 0 {
            print("\(self.secondsRemaining) seconds left to finish")
            self.secondsRemaining -= 1
        }
        else {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.progress.text = "DONE"
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add `@objc` in front of the function name to expose it to ObjC runtime. You can read more about that [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objc-attribute).